# How to get the handler of DialogFragment after rotation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` attached to an activity and when screen rotates, the dialogFragment life cycle will automatically activated by Android framework, my question is how can I get the handler object of the dialogFragment after rotation because I want to dimiss it in the code where I need. The former handler object is null because activity is destryed when rotate.

I try to put `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreate` function in DialogFragment, but I meet the crash when I rotate the screen:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication, PID: 6075
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication/com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
    at android.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:476)
    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2228)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:992)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:152)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6245)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6253)
    .....
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how are you adding that dialog?

Comment: Add it in the acitivity using newInstace. mDialog = PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.newInstance(this);

Comment: You just showed how you created the fragment. How do you show the fragment?

Comment: I write a function called showPasswordDialog in DialogFragment class, and after create it I will call this function, should I add this function in some life cycle function?

Comment: Can you post your code so that it will be more easier to understand?